# Django WebSocket not working inside a container but works outside of it

Tags: django, docker, websocket, containers

I am trying to do a connection to a websocket  from a html page in django. This works when i run it outside a container but it stops working inside of it .

My server inside my docker compose.

```
server:
        stdin_open: true # docker run -i
        tty: true        # docker run -t
        build: 
            dockerfile: server.Dockerfile
            context: ./
        volumes:
            - /home/$USER/.ssh:/root/.ssh
        ports: 
          - '8000:8000'
        networks:
          drone_net:
            ipv4_address: 10.10.10.2
```

the url I use in my html page

```
let url = `ws://localhost:8000/ws/socket-server/`
```

The error i get: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/socket-server/' failed:

This is my routing for the websocket :

```
websocket_urlpatterns=[
    re_path(r'ws/socket-server/',consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

I first thought it was localhost not working but my http request works in the containe as well.

I tried to change the value of the url with different ones.
I thought it was localhost that wasnt working properly but i also use local host for http request and they were fine in the container.
I was expecting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Weirldy it was a problem of package channel Version. In the docker file, I took the most recent version of channels: 4.0.0. While my local computer was using channels.version 3.0.5. When I downgraded the version, it solved my problem.